# Will a DropDownList html helper work correctly with a IList<SelectListItem>?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having problems with getting a DropDownList to correctly select the right value and display it.

I am using the following:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.AdminSummaries[index].Status, AdminStatusReference.GetAdminStatusOptions(), new { id = string.Format("Status_{0}",index ) })
```

Is it okay that AdminStatusReference.GetAdminStatusOptions() returns a List or MUST it return an IEnumerable?

Comment: a List is an IEnumerable so I wouldn't think that is your problem

Comment: what do you mean by correctly select the right value?

do you mean default selected value or when you select an item and post the form the selectedItem is wrong??

Comment: What are the problems you're having? It has nothing to do with List against IEnumerable.

Comment: The problems I am having is it does not seem to mark anything as selected. I already have another thread open but no new responses on that :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IList<AdminSummary> AdminSummaries { get; set; }
}

public class AdminSummary
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

public static class AdminStatusReference
{
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetAdminStatusOptions()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "status 1" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "status 2" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "status 3" },
        };
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            AdminSummaries = new[]
            {
                // preselect the first item
                new AdminSummary { Status = "1" },

                // preselect the second item
                new AdminSummary { Status = "2" },

                // nothing will be preselected because there is no xxx Value in the list
                new AdminSummary { Status = "xxx" },
            }.ToList()
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model MyViewModel
@for (int index = 0; index < Model.AdminSummaries.Count; index++)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.AdminSummaries[index].Status, 
        new SelectList(
            AdminStatusReference.GetAdminStatusOptions(),
            "Value",
            "Text",
            Model.AdminSummaries[index].Status
        )
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be fine.
`List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`

Answer (score 0):

for using

```
@Html.DropDownListFor<>
```

in my projects I have always used a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` in my View and therefore before hand I have set which item has the propery "Selected" as true. This will then set the default item.

[image]

forgot I could edit my original answer :P
here is the html rendered on my project

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding this correctly. I thought that DropDownList would take as its input the field value and then mark the matched one with the keyword selected.